# Carousel loose responsive behaviour with "image in div" zooming on hoover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, carousel

Using **[flickity carousel](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/)** I've created the following example here in **[codepen.io link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGbzyR?editors=110)**. Here is CSS code I've implemented:

**CSS**

```
.image-hoover { 
  overflow: hidden;
}



.image-hoover img {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.02);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
  transform: scale(1.02);
  -webkit-transition: all 10s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 10s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 10s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 10s ease;
  transition:         all 10s ease;
}



.image-hoover:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.06);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.06);
  transform: scale(1.06);
  -webkit-transition: all 10s linear;
  -moz-transition:    all 10s linear;
  -o-transition:      all 10s linear;
  -ms-transition:     all 10s linear;
  transition:         all 10s linear;
}
```

The issue I can't figure out is that images loose responsive behavior only until I turn off this part:

```
.image-hoover img {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.02);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
  transform: scale(1.02);
  -webkit-transition: all 10s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 10s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 10s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 10s ease;
  transition:         all 10s ease;
}
```

But in this case when you unhover the image returns back to it size very fast loosing the transition effect, can you please suggest how to figure out this issue?

1. [**Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGbzyR?editors=110) the responsive behavior of image is present, but zoom effect on hoover loose transition.

 2. In [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adWQBz?editors=110) example you can notice that transition works great, but if you resize the window images loose their responsive behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you said for the transition to apply on **all** actions, so the 10s transition happens also when the images change thier when the screen changes width.

You will need to change

```
-webkit-transition: all 10s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 10s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 10s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 10s ease;
  transition:         all 10s ease;
```

to

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 10s ease;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 10s ease;
  -o-transition:      transform 10s ease;
  -ms-transition:     transform 10s ease;
  transition:         transform 10s ease;
```

And remove the transition from the :hover.
This will now work.

Fiddle-http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJWQRq?editors=110

Comment: Thank you, BinaryGhost. That works perfect and helped me a lot!